# How to display highchart series line marker symbol from local image object?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to get a few custom symbols in Highcharts. I'm currently following the specs:

```
marker: {
  symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
}
```

However, this requires a network call, which I'm trying to avoid by pre-caching the image. I created a custom image before loading the chart.

```
var sun = new Image();
sun.src = 'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png'
```

As expected, this code preloads the image (as seen in the network tab of Chrome Developer Console), but when I load the graph the same url loads again. My guess is that this is particular to Highchart library.

I also tried to directly set the symbol value to the image like `symbol: sun` but that didn't work.

I'm wondering how else to approach this. Maybe converting the local image into a blob and then setting it as the value of the symbol? I'll try that but would welcome any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Turns out that we can just convert the image to base 64 and then setting that as symbol. Instead of 100 - 800 ms in loading time I get about < 100 microseconds.

Comment: I am currently trying to use a base64 image but don't know how to call it. Can you show me how to set the symbol to a base64 image ?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Bowen Yang, yes, base64 works. Convert image on https://elmah.io/tools/base64-image-encoder/ , then copy code in CSS usage to highchart symbol.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31572967)